# Angular 4 tree shaking with Rollup plugin

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-aot, tree-shaking

I'm trying to use Tree shaking in my application with the Rollup plugin.

When I run `node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup-config.js` I get this error:

**`[!] Error: 'Subject' is not exported by node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js`**

This is my `rollup-config.js` file:

```
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        file: 'src/build.js', // output a single application bundle
        format: 'iife',
    },
    sourceMap: false,
    onwarn: function (warning) {
        // Skip certain warnings

        // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
        if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') { return; }

        // console.warn everything else
        console.warn(warning.message);
    },
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, module: true }),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
            include: 'node_modules/ng2-cache-service/**',
            include: 'node_modules/ng2-dragula/**'
        }),
        uglify()
    ]
};
```

I used to have similar errors for the `ng2-cache-service` and `ng2-dragula` modules but I solved them by importing those into the commonjs

I can not do the same with `rxjs/Subject`

Comment: `[angularjs]` != `[angular]`. Be careful with tags! ;-)

Comment: You're doing `import { Subject }` somewhere and `Subject` isn't exported by that module. If it's a CommonJS module, you might need to do `import module` and then use `module.Subject`.